# issues with template <> during scip installation

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, scip, pyscipopt, scipopt

I am trying to install scipoptsuite v6.0.1 (https://scipopt.org/download.php?fname=scipoptsuite-6.0.1.tgz) on my Mac M1. Following the instruction in the website:

Link to the changesoplex.cpp file: https://github.com/benmhamed-a/scipopts/blob/main/changesoplex.cpp

```
1. tar xvzf scip-x.y.z.tgz            
2. cd scip-x.y.z 
3. mkdir build 
4. cd build 
5. cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
6. make
7. make check               
8. make install
```

Following these steps and at the step number (5) I get the following error that I couldn't solve:

```
[  8%] Linking C executable ../../bin/zimpl
[  8%] Built target zimpl
-- Git hash: e89d7d5
[  8%] Built target soplex_update_githash
[  8%] Building CXX object soplex/src/CMakeFiles/libsoplex-pic.dir/soplex/changesoplex.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/intelligentica/Desktop/scipoptsuite-6.0.1/soplex/src/soplex/changesoplex.cpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/soplex/spxdefines.h:59:
/opt/homebrew/include/soplex/config.h:14:9: warning: 'SOPLEX_WITH_GMP' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SOPLEX_WITH_GMP
        ^
<command line>:1:9: note: previous definition is here
#define SOPLEX_WITH_GMP 1
        ^
In file included from /Users/intelligentica/Desktop/scipoptsuite-6.0.1/soplex/src/soplex/changesoplex.cpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/soplex/spxdefines.h:59:
/opt/homebrew/include/soplex/config.h:17:9: warning: 'SOPLEX_WITH_ZLIB' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SOPLEX_WITH_ZLIB
        ^
<command line>:2:9: note: previous definition is here
#define SOPLEX_WITH_ZLIB 1
        ^
In file included from /Users/intelligentica/Desktop/scipoptsuite-6.0.1/soplex/src/soplex/changesoplex.cpp:19:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/soplex/spxdefines.h:63:
In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp:10:
```

Comment: Can you include to question part of code which contains this line `changesoplex.cpp:495:17` and context around it?

Comment: BTW looks like you are showing tail of errors `20 errors generated`. Most important is first error, since later errors can be consequence of the first one.

Comment: I don't have access to the code of scipoptsuite. I download it from the official website and expected the installation to pass following the instructions.

Comment: You are showing us compilation error, so you have have access to the code.

Comment: I have updated the error i get by showing the first error lines

Comment: I have added the file mentioned in the error

Comment: 1. Respective header is also needed. 2. You head of provided build logs which contains only warnings. Provide logs from from first error.

Comment: I hope you have a really good reason to use an extremely outdated 6.X version, which even predates M1 hardware.